# Synchronization-factory deletes folder for sftp:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have this issue where the first time this code is processed, it works well, but then the second time (first and second run is based on the set cron), it looks for a file in the failed folder and then deletes the success folder and copies it into the failed folder. I have no idea why this is happening??

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="sftpInboundAdapter" 
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    remote-directory="${remote}"
    local-directory="${local.download.folder}"
    delete-remote-files="false"
    channel="InboundChannel"
    filter="CompositeIncomingFilesFilter"
    auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller cron="*/60 * * * * ?" error-channel="PollerErrorChannel">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory" >
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('${local.download.folder}' + 'success/' + payload.name))" channel="afterCommitSuccessChannel" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('${local.download.folder}' + 'failed/' + payload.name))" channel="afterRollbackFailedChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="afterCommitSuccessChannel" />
<int:channel id="afterRollbackFailedChannel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="afterCommitSuccessChannel" expression="'File saved and processed: ' + payload"  level="INFO" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="afterRollbackFailedChannel" expression="'File was rollbacked: ' + payload"  level="INFO" />

<bean id="CompositeIncomingFilesFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean id="SftpFilterAlreadyDownloadedFiles" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="persistingMetadataStore" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="prefix_" />
                <property name = "flushOnUpdate" value = "true"/>
            </bean>         
            <bean id="SftpFilterSimple" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="*123*.txt" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>      
</bean>
```

My logs display the following:

```
    2018-10-23 11:29:04.597  INFO 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : File saved and processed: true
File saved and processed: true
2018-10-23 11:30:00.002  INFO 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=\local\failed, headers={id=6afc5dfb-5dd4-b234-5c35-a60a42931524, timestamp=1540287000002}]]
Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=\local\failed, headers={id=6afc5dfb-5dd4-b234-5c35-a60a42931524, timestamp=1540287000002}]]
2018-10-23 11:30:00.023 ERROR 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] i.a.ErrorMessageLoggerActivator          : Message containing error inside channel: GenericMessage [payload=\local\failed, headers={id=6afc5dfb-5dd4-b234-5c35-a60a42931524, timestamp=1540287000002}]
Message containing error inside channel: GenericMessage [payload=\local\failed, headers={id=6afc5dfb-5dd4-b234-5c35-a60a42931524, timestamp=1540287000002}]
2018-10-23 11:30:00.023 ERROR 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] i.a.ErrorMessageLoggerActivator          : ErrorMessageLoggerActivator exception: 
ErrorMessageLoggerActivator exception: 
2018-10-23 11:30:17.180  WARN 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] sftpInboundLogger                : \local\failed
\local\failed
2018-10-23 11:30:17.192  INFO 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : File was rollbacked: false
File was rollbacked: false
2018-10-23 11:30:17.193 ERROR 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-4] i.e.InboundStreamErrorHandler            : java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\failed (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\failed (Access is denied)
2018-10-23 11:31:00.001  INFO 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}]]
Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}]]
2018-10-23 11:31:00.022  WARN 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-5] sftpInboundLogger                : \local\success
\local\success
2018-10-23 11:31:00.032  INFO 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : File was rollbacked: true
File was rollbacked: true
2018-10-23 11:31:00.034 ERROR 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-5] i.a.ErrorMessageLoggerActivator          : Message containing error inside channel: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}], headers={id=9ac1bff3-2296-6166-115e-1e6fbc2ed304, timestamp=1540287060033}]
Message containing error inside channel: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}], headers={id=9ac1bff3-2296-6166-115e-1e6fbc2ed304, timestamp=1540287060033}]
2018-10-23 11:31:00.043 ERROR 12244 --- [ask-scheduler-5] i.a.ErrorMessageLoggerActivator          : ErrorMessageLoggerActivator exception: 

org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.transform(AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.FileToByteArrayTransformer.transformFile(FileToByteArrayTransformer.java:32)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.FileToByteArrayTransformer.transformFile(FileToByteArrayTransformer.java:28)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.transform(AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.java:87)
    ... 44 common frames omitted

ErrorMessageLoggerActivator exception: 
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\local\success, headers={id=4e12f55a-2b2a-ca79-fad3-1325b7b698fa, timestamp=1540287060001}]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.transform(AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \local\success (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.FileToByteArrayTransformer.transformFile(FileToByteArrayTransformer.java:32)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.FileToByteArrayTransformer.transformFile(FileToByteArrayTransformer.java:28)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.transformer.AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.transform(AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.java:87)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: May we see more stack trace? And, please, format it as a code not like a quote. Just try to left it as it is in logs. Also it isn't clear how payload cal be `\local\success` if you deal with files. Looks like some your custom code does some logic you don't show for us. Also bear in mind that `renameTo()` is going to work only if all the folders are present. If you remove that `success` dir, then you are going really to end up with a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank  you for your response. So that is the issue, i create the folder "success" and then it copies the file and then it moves the folder with the file under failure. so the rename somehow is copying or deleting when the code is ran a second time.  What i want is to have the file move to success or failure based on whether the file was polled properly or not and display that to the logs.  Then i will write new code to process the failures at a later stage or then determine why this file failed from the remote client server.

Answer (score 0):

> and then it moves the folder with the file under failure

OK. So, when you rename a `/success` directory to something else, it disappears and, of course, you can't write to the `/success` anymore. You have to have it to be created in advice for writing files into it. You need to consider to rename each file individually if you don't have control over `/success` directory created before writing files.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for your response.  So i have two folders in the same directory: /local/failed/ and /local/success.  The cron runs every second, just for testing purposes. when it runs on the 2nd second, the success folder is copied into failed, with the specific file. so now i have /local/failed/success/file - I did not rename them myself, this is completely the code itself. So basically the first second it runs correctly and it is what i want. I will then at the end of the day run the files which were in failed folder. is there maybe a better way to do this? and still keep the files?

Comment: * the success folder is copied into failed,*. According your situation it is **moved**. Therefore it is removed in its original location. I don't understand what you would like to achieve, but moving directory into another one makes you to create it for the next file. Maybe you need to take a look into the `java.nio.file.File.move()` instead of `renameTo()` ?